# How to estimate the distribution of data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I want to estimate the parameters for the distribution of the following data:

```
25 17 16 17 16 16 17 16 16 17 16 17 16 60 13 17 31 16 17 17 16 42 16 17 19 17 16 17 17 17
63 47 27 27 74 79 23 30 66 42 30 15 20 20 21 22 22 19 21 21 19 20 18 21 22 19 21 20 22 20
21 18 20 20 20 23 21 29 22 22 20 50 28 20 20 28
```

so that i can find $P(X<x)$. To me the data looks like a shifted normal distribution, or do you think it looks like something else? Is there a way to check other distributions?
[image]

If it is normal, then would i simply find the mean and SD and then integrate to find the CDF to get $P(X<x)$? i.e. the mean is 24.4 and SD is 13.7, therefore to find the $P(X<20)$ then `pnorm(20, 24.4, 13.7)` returns 0.37 which is very low considering most people are actually younger than 20 in the data.

I feel it must be another distribution, perhaps lognormal? But when i do `plnorm(20, meanlog = 3, sdlog = 0.39, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)` then i return 0.49, which is not much better.

Comment: It is rare for a blind search for distributions to be meaningful.  What statistical problem are you hoping to solve in this way?

Comment: From what you say the data are people's ages in years, which rules out many distributions as wrong in principle or useless in practice. The normal isn't even a sensible starting point. That only helps a bit. The overarching problem is that: there are probably hundreds of brand-name distributions invented in various ways, but going the other direction from real data to find even plausible candidates can be very hard, not least many set-ups are heterogeneous in some sense so that data may be a mixture.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider a mixture of normals, with parameters estimated via EM algorithm?

Comment: Any parametric assumption will be questionable, and if you have no subject matter information that suggests otherwise, you might well use the empirical distribution or a kernel-density estimator as already plotted in read in the image. (You may ask "which of these?" but the data as they are can't decide this for you.) PS: Chances are you want a kernel density estimator with bandwidth wide enough that the estimated density never goes down to zero over the range of the data.

Answer (score 2):

You say your goal is to estimate $P(X<x)$ i.e. the cumulative distribution or the quantiles of the univariate distribution. Call such an estimator $\hat{F}$ so that $\hat{F}(x)$ is our best guess of the probability that any randomly sampled $X$ is less than $x$.

Nick's answer clarifies a common approach in some very specialized areas. Suppose for instance you need to estimate some extreme quantiles such as in reliability analysis, i.e. how to choose an expiry in milk so that only 1 in 10,000 gallons of milk expire prior to the expiry? This is theoretically possible in a sample much smaller than 10,000 when the distribution of expiry is known and only the parameters  need to be estimated via ML. It's not uncommon in such an analysis to choose from among a set of distributions as well, and pick the most favored by the BIC. When it concerns behavior in the tails, there are quite a few distributions that project (and weight) out lying observations very different. So, you have Gumbel, SHASH, log normal distributions, among others which would generally model "skewed" data.

A completely different approach: Have you considered the power and flexibility of the empirical distribution function? If you're not modeling extreme values, I can see that the number of samples is quite large. The empirical distribution uses $\hat{F}(x) = \mathbb{F}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n I(x_i < x) / n$. In other word, at every point the quantile is given by the percentage of observations below this point. We just assume the sample *is* the distribution. The sample mean *is* the population mean, the sample standard deviation *is* the population standard deviation. There is a robust corpus of theory on EDFs, their uncertainty and inference. For instance, a test for difference in two EDFs yields the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I find EDFs are very intuitive and useful for analysis and applications.

Comment: I was thinking of the empirical distribution as well, see comment at about the same time. However I suspect that it may not be appropriate to estimate a probability zero anywhere inside the range of the observed data. (Question was asked 19 months ago so chances are we won't find out.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig if the data are continuously valued, the probability of a specific point is *always* 0 :) You also have kernal density estimators if a density is desired, but OP's question was to get $P(X<x)$.

Comment: Fair enough, but then still the emp. distribution gives $\hat P(X<32)=\hat P(X<40)$, and the observations are in fact integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

The data are not symmetric, positive and have a fat right tail, but let's test on normality with the Shapiro test

```
x <- c(25, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 60, 13, 17, 31, 16, 17, 17, 16, 42, 16, 17, 19, 17, 16, 17, 17, 17, 63, 47, 27, 27, 74, 79, 23, 30, 66, 42, 30, 15, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 19, 21, 21, 19, 20, 18, 21, 22, 19, 21, 20, 22, 20, 21, 18, 20, 20, 20, 23, 21, 29, 22, 22, 20, 50, 28, 20, 20, 28)
 
shapiro.test(x)
# 
#   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#
# data:  x
# W = 0.62669, p-value = 1.33e-12
```

From the  `p-value = 1.33e-12` one can see that `x` is not from normal disribution.
Poisson distibution is not candidate too because `mean(x)` $\not\approx$ `sd(x)`. You can add the potential distributions from the table into the `dist` and check the output. For example, lognormal and gamma distibutions.

[image]

```
library(fitdistrplus)
dist <- c("lnorm", "gamma")

for(i in length(dist)){
  fit <- fitdist(x, dist[i])
  gofstat(fit)
  plot(fit)
}
```

Comment: I've guessed that partical was meant to be _partial_. If _practical_ was intended, please edit accordingly.